# How to solve github conflicts?

Tags: git, github-pages, git-merge-conflict

I am taken course in udacity (not nanodegree) . It discuss git and github . In discussing pull and push , I asked my self what if a conflict happens . Several developers commits the files of course a conflict will happen .. i didn't find an answer .
Can anyone answer my question? 
I tried to make commits in the same line in github and local repo and a conflict happened!

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-on-github/

Comment: Okay bro i know how to solve conflicts .. but i it will be alot of conflicts because of the number of developers commit the files

Comment: What's the difference if it's many conflicts or just one? Usually it's common practice to rebase your branch frequently to avoid this situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid git conflicts in a team?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490873/how-to-avoid-git-conflicts-in-a-team)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+how+to+avoid+conflicts

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that the mechanism for resolving conflicts is called merging.

"i didn't find an answer"  - I'm not sure where you looked, but here a some articles to get you started:

- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging
- https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-on-github/
- https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing
- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge