# merge code problem from develop to master on git flow

Tags: git, git-flow

On gitflow. After a hotfix commit on the master branch without merge to develop, what should we do when we merge code from develop to master next time?

1. If we direct do the merge, code will be merged, and there will be a diff between master and develop.
2. Or we need a code review here?

Answer (score 0):

A hotfix is not always merges to develop (since the bug fixed might not be relevant anymore in develop which has since moved on)

As [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56606697/6309), you might consider merging master to develop first, resolve any conflict, make sure everything works, then merge develop to master.